# How can I include a variable in a dynamic row query with Net::Google::Spreadsheets?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I want to pass a variable in a structured query to a Google Spreadsheet.

This works:

```
$R = $LS->row({sq => 'columnname = "blah"});
```

And this doesn't:

```
$Q = "blah";
$R = $LS->row({sq => 'columnname = "$Q"'});
```

I can make this extremely simple, and it still will not return any content. I've tried numeric arguments, encoded arguments, etc. It never works when assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't interpolated inside single quotes. Change

```
$R = $LS->row({sq => 'columnname = "$Q"'});
```

to

```
$R = $LS->row({sq => qq{columnname = "$Q"} });
```